Printing multiple AnchorPanes on their own pages
I have a javafx TabPane that I want to be able to print. The TabPane has two tabs, and I want each tab to be printed on its own page. I created a button on one of the tabs with the onAction function to run a method called onPrint. The button will print a table within one tab and another table in the other.
The printer.fxml file
<ScrollPane fx:id="assessment"/>
    <Pane fx:id="printPane">
    <TabPane prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="937.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <Tab text="Issues">
                <AnchorPane fx:id="issuesTab" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="519.0" prefWidth="585.0">
                 <Text text="here is some text" />
                 <Button fx:id="print" layoutX="82.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPrint" text="print" /> 
                </AnchorPane>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Function">
                <AnchorPane fx:id="FunctionTab" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                     <Text text="here is some text"/>
                </AnchorPane>
        </Tab>
</Pane>
</Scrollpane>

I've tried several different ways to get this to work properly. I'll walk through them below.
The printerController file is as follows:
public ScrollPane assessment; 
public Pane printerPane; 
public AnchorPane issuesTab;
public AnchorPane functionTab;


 public void onPrint(ActionEvent event) {
        printPane.getChildren().addAll(issuesTab, functionTab);
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        job.getJobSettings().setPageRanges(new PageRange(1, 2));
        if (job.showPrintDialog(printPane.getScene().getWindow())){
            boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, printPane);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
    }

Currently this works but it adds both tables ontop of each other. I've tried to use the setPageRanges function to set a page range but I cannot get it to work propertly.
I then thought maybe I need to create a brand new pane for each tab and then add those to a group and it'll print separately.
    private Node toPrint;

    private Node printAllPages(){
        if(toPrint== null){
            Group group = new Group();
            group.getChildren().addAll(
                    new Pane(issuesTab),
                    new Pane(functionTab)
            );
            notToPrint = group;
        }
        return notToPrint;
    }
 public void onPrint(ActionEvent event) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if(job.showPrintDialog(notToPrint.getScene().getWindow())){
            boolean success = job.printPage(printAllPages());
            if(success){
                job.endJob();
            }
        }


    }

However this results in the following error - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Node.getScene()" because "this.notToPrint" is null. I also don't believe this is the right approach.
Are there any Printer, PageLayout or PrinterJob settings that I need to apply so that each AnchorPane can be printed on separate pages?

Edits made:
Per @SedJ601 advice on how to fix this issue. I went through the link he provided and decided to try this -
PrintController.java
    public TabPane allTabs;
   Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        if(job.showPrintDialog(allTabs.getScene().getWindow())){
            double pagePrintableHeight = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight();
            double pagePrintableWidth = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth();
            double scaleX = pagePrintableWidth / allTabs.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
            double localScale = scaleX;


            double numberOfPages = Math.ceil((allTabs.getPrefWidth()) * localScale) / pagePrintableHeight;
            System.out.println(numberOfPages);

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++){ job.printPage(pageLayout, allTabs.get(i)); } job.endJob();
        }else{
            System.out.println("This did not work");
        }

Print.fxml
<ScrollPane fx:id="assessment">
<TabPane fx:id="allTabs" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="937.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <Tab text="Issues">
        <content>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="issuesTab" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="519.0" prefWidth="585.0">
             <Text text="some text" />
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Function">
        <content>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="functionTab" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
               <Text text="some text" />
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
    </Tab>
</TabPane>

However this is printing only the first tab. I tried setting the numberOfPages value equal to 10.0 and still only the first tab prints. How do I edit either the for loop to loop through both tabs or change the numberOfPages to accurately find all pages?

I would follow the strategy to add AnchorPanes for each tab content, then you can you can use PrinterJob class to print each node separately

Check your spelling printerPane vs printPane.

If you want to print the AnchorPanes on two different pages, print the AnchorPanes individually and not the Print(er)Pane

@SedJ601 - I fixed the spelling with pinterPane and printPane. It must have been one of the many ways I was trying to fix the issue.  I do not want to print the panes individually. I want to print them within the same PrintJob just on different pages.

Yeah, that means you want to print them individually.  Do something like this -> for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {  job.printPage(pageLayout, tblvMain); }  Where you loop through the AnchorPanes.

@SedJ601  -
public TabPane allTabs;
if(job.showPrintDialog(allTabs.getScene().getWindow())){
double numberOfPages = Math.ceil((allTabs.getPrefWidth()) * localScale) / pagePrintableHeight;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, allTabs);
if (success) {
System.out.println("success!");
job.endJob();
}
}
}
This is what I've created from your link. However it's only printing the first page of the tab. How do I correct the numberOfPages?

you should be doing something like for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAnchorPanes; i++){ job.printPage(pageLayout, anchorPaneList.get(i)); } job.endJob(); I normally print to PDF to save paper until things are figured out. Create an MVCE for better help.

When replying to comments, especially if you are writing code in comments, it is often better to edit the question and put the replies and the code (with appropriate formatting) in the question.  You can quote somebody else's comment when doing that if context is needed.  It is just really hard to understand the current state of the question when everything is back and forth in comments and the code in comments is unformatted snippets.

@jewelsea - Ah, okay I actually didn't know I could edit questions I have already posted. I'll do that. Thank you.

Where you able to figure it out? Are you still having issues?

I updated my MVCE to make it easier to print tabs. Now, all you need to do is give your TabPane an fx:id and call that fx:id in your controller like printNodes(theFxId.getTabs(), scene);

If you are going to only have two Tabs then I think the following code should work.
public void onPrint(ActionEvent event) {
        printPane.getChildren().addAll(issuesTab, functionTab);
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        job.getJobSettings().setPageRanges(new PageRange(1, 2));
        if (job.showPrintDialog(printPane.getScene().getWindow())){
            //if the number of tabs is variable use a loop and print each tab.
            boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, issuesTab);
            boolean successTwo = job.printPage(pageLayout, functionTab);
            if (success && successTwo) {
                job.endJob();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Printing Error!");
           }
        }
    }

I typed the above code in here without testing it. It may have errors.
Here is a MCVE.
//Original code from https://jenkov.com/tutorials/javafx/tabpane.html
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.print.PageLayout;
import javafx.print.PageOrientation;
import javafx.print.Paper;
import javafx.print.Printer;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {       
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        VBox.setVgrow(tabPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
        
        StackPane stackPane1 = new StackPane(new Label("This is tab 1"));
        StackPane stackPane2 = new StackPane(new Label("This is tab 2"));
        StackPane stackPane3 = new StackPane(new Label("This is tab 3"));

        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1", stackPane1);
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2"  , stackPane2);
        Tab tab3 = new Tab("Tab 3" , stackPane3);

        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab3);
        
        VBox root = new VBox(tabPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        
        Button button = new Button("Print Nodes");
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            printNodes(tabPane.getTabs(), scene);
        });        
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX App");

        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    
    public void printNodes(ObservableList<Tab> nodesFromSameScene, Scene scene)
    {
        boolean control = true;
        
        Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        
        if (job.showPrintDialog(scene.getWindow()))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < nodesFromSameScene.size(); i++)
            {
                if(!job.printPage(pageLayout, nodesFromSameScene.get(i).getContent()))
                {
                    control = false;
                    break;
                }            
            }

            if(control)
            {
                job.endJob();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Printing Error!");
            }
        }        
    }
}

Output - Saved as PDF instead of printing!

